# how to web scrape a google results?

Tags: python, web, screen-scraping

I need to get the contents of a google result page, like the following:

[image]

[image]

I tried to use xpath using this code, but did not find the element

```
import lxml.html
import requests

html= requests.get("https://www.google.com/search?q=curitiba")
lxml = lxml.html.fromstring(html.content)




test=lxml.xpath('/html/body/div[7]/div[2]/div[9]/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/span/text()')

print(test)
```

this is the xpath that chrome itself provides

how can i get the contents of this page?

Answer (score 0):

Use `BeautifulSoup`:

```
import bs4
import requests
html = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search?q=curitiba")
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html.content)

targeth3 = soup.find("h3", string="Descrição")  # Finds the h3 tag above the span
targetspantext = targeth3.nextSibling.text  # access the text in the target span tag
```

EDIT: You cannot retrieve that box with requests, since it's loaded with javascript. You can use selenium or use https://serpapi.com/. You can retrieve that box using the API, it is called "knowledge-graph"

Comment: I tried to use it before but it didn't work, now when I put this same code it gives an error: NoneType' object has no attribute 'nextSibling

Comment: bro, this serpapi was exactly what i needed, thank you very much